# How connect socket in different port in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, html, websocket

This code is working fine.
I am successfully tested socket connection in my system in port:80 but not able to connect in different port .

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = 8000;

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = gethostbyname('localhost');

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}


echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";

?>
```

Output:

```
Attempting to connect to '127.0.0.1' on port '8000'...socket_connect() failed.
Reason: () Connection refused
Closing socket...OK.
```

I need to connect in port different than 80, so please any Idea?
Thank You

Comment: Lots of firewalls and servers block/ignore unexpected port use.

Comment: I am testing in local and facing that problem.

Comment: Do you have something listening on 8000?

Comment: how can i test that my port is listening or not? i am using ubuntu os.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to a generic port if there isn't a server socket opened there.